# Measuring class imbalance of a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes

Is there a way to measure the balance (i.e. ideal number of positive samples for machine learning) of a dataset? A citation will also be useful.

Comment: You will have to tell us what "balance" means and what your data set is like before we can answer this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with any works specifically on measuring class (im)balance.
A simple way of reporting class (im)balance however is by the ratio between the number of instances per class and the total number of instances, so

$$(\frac{n_{y_1}}{N},\frac{n_{y_2}}{N},\cdots,\frac{n_{y_i}}{N}) $$

with $n_{y_1}$ being the number of observations of class $y_1$ and $N$ being the total number of observations.

When working in a context where a time variable is associated with the observations, this can of course be applied to multiple time windows to report a possible change in these ratios.

Comment: perhapps it would be better to multiply all values by $i$. That is, the amount of classes, this way, we know that a perfectly balanced data set should have all ratios equal to 1. The metrics for reporting class (im)balance would become $(i\cdot\frac{n_{y_1}}{N},\ldots, i\cdot\frac{n_{y_i}}{N})$

Comment: @Rickyfox, thanks for the answer. What is the ideal value of this metric for a balanced dataset? Is it 50%?

Comment: This is a question of what you would consider balanced. If you define it as 'all classes should be equally frequent' then 0.5 would be correct for a binary problem. Note, however, that this doesn't necessarily need to hold to be able to make good predictions.

Comment: Measure the imbalance (balance) as the **percent in the minority class**.  It's simple and everyone understands it.  Do not represent it as a ratio-- this gets highly non-linear and doesn't generalize to multi-class problems.

A perfectly balanced binary-class dataset would be 50%.   If we have 100 classes that are perfectly balanced, we'd expect 1% for the minority class, which is already hard; but if the minority class in this case were 0.001% we know it's even more imbalanced; it can be useful to report the **number** of train/test examples in the minority class as well.